# About Google Maps SDK for iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps

I am not able to find any information about the use of marker info windows in view Controllers using the Google Maps SDK for iOS. I am using version 1.7.2.

In my app I am populating the mapView with markers downloaded from JSON objects.
I would need the app user to tap on a marker info windows, and then a marker details viewController should be shown.

Please, any advice or link to any tutorial about the use of markers is welcome.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google Maps SDK for iOS Developer Guide contains just what you need: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/marker

At the bottom of the page you'll find info on Info windows.

Comment: Thank you Paulo, I know this document, but it doesn't tell how to include an action to the infoWindow that would allow to open a detail ViewController with details about the marker object.

Comment: To do that you could create your own infoWindow which is just a UIView returned from `mapView:markerInfoWindow`.

You have to set up your view to become the map's delegate and implement the `GMSMapViewDelegate` protocol. More info here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/protocol_g_m_s_map_view_delegate-p#a961e81669891377c9ebee752ce53340f

Comment: Thank you, I will create a custom infoWindow and open a new question if needed...